# How can I enable Explcit API mode in an Android/Kotlin library module?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-library

I use Android 4.0.1, and Kotlin 1.4.10.
I tried to insert:

```
kotlin {
   explicitApi()
}
```

at the top level of the module build.gradle file, but Android Studio seems to ignore it.

I tried to insert the same block in the `android { ... }` block, but Android Studio seems to ignore it.

I tried to insert `explicitApi()` in `android.kotlinOptions { ... }` block, but the Gradle project sync failed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```groovy
android {
  kotlinOptions {
    freeCompilerArgs += '-Xexplicit-api=warning'
  }
}
```

Comment: Note the implications for tests. Check [KT-37652](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-37652) for tracking the status of this issue.

Comment: I think the implications are kind of a deal-breaker for now, so worth considering 